# What's the logic behind this: $UMU^\dagger$? How do we derive it?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that this $UMU^\dagger$ is used to express a matrix M from one initial basis to another one with the help of the unitary matrix $U$.

I don't understand why it's like this: $UMU^\dagger$ and not $U^\dagger MU$?

Can anyone give me an intuitive explanation and possibly a derivation?

Comment: Either works since $U^{\dagger}MU=(U^{-1})M(U^{-1})^{\dagger}$. Writing either way is basically just choosing $U$ or $U^{-1}$ as your unitary matrix

Comment: Dagger is usually used for the pseudo-inverse.

Comment: The transpose is usually latexed as $A^T$ ie A^T.